# How to get the title of a link using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the title of a webpage without opening it, i.e. without using `window.open()`.
I basically want to check whether the page i am providing the link for exists or an error is returned.

What I am trying is checking for similar links. Here is the code
(I want to know when to break out of this loop, i.e. at what point the link I am writing exists).

```
document.getElementById("TOI").innerHTML="<p>";
if (month<10) var m="0"+month;
else var m=month;
for(var i=1;;i++){
    alert("ji");
    var a="http://epaper.timesofindia.com/Repository/CAP/"+year+"/"+m+"/"+date+"/CAP_"+year+"_"+month+"_"+date+"_"+i+".pdf";
    alert(a);
    var link=window.open(a);
    window.focus();
    alert(link.location);
    alert(link.document.title);
    if(link.document.title!="The page cannot be found"){
        link.close();
        document.getElementById("TOI").innerHTML=document.getElementById("TOI").innerHTML+"<a href='http://epaper.timesofindia.com/Repository/CAP/"+year+"/"+m+"/"+date+"/CAP_"+year+"_"+month+"_"+date+"_"+i+".pdf' target=_blank>Page "+i+"</a>    ";
        }
    else{link.close();break;}
}
document.getElementById("TOI").innerHTML=document.getElementById("TOI").innerHTML+"<\p>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See to check if a url exists or not, you must use a server-side scripting language. Javascript is client-side and can't access server. So, first of all make a server side script (maybe php) that returns the status of url that you wanna check. Then from javascript side, use an ajax call to get the result of that script. That way you can check your url array, if all of them exists or not.

Comment: I may post some code-snippets if you want to follow this method.

Comment: how shd I proceed with php[I want to know status of page on some remote server]

Comment: Ok I am using php but since I am asking for a lot of files it is taking too much time.
Here's what I used
`$i=59;
  for(;$i>0;$i--){
   $ideal="HTTP/1.0 200 OK";
   $url = 'http://epaper.timesofindia.com/Repository/ETD/'.date("Y").'/'.date("m").'/'.date("d").'/ETD_'.date("Y").'_'.date("m").'_'.date("d").'_'.$i.'.pdf';
   $status=get_headers($url);
   $status=$status['0'];
   if($status==$ideal){
    echo $i;
    break;
   }
  }`
any other option???

Comment: hmm. that's the perfect code for it i think. try uploading this script on a web server. i mean professional hosting. that can download the headers pretty fast as they use high speed internet connection. i don't see any way to optimize this code. sorry.

Answer (score -1):

```
var attribute = element.getAttribute("title");
```

Comment: Since i am new to js ,I need to know where to enter link to page I need title of?

Answer (score -1):

> I want to get title of a webpage
>   without opening it(that is without
>   using window.open()) I basically want
>   to check whether the page i am
>   providing the link for exists or an
>   error is returned

Just because a page has a title doesn't mean it exists.

http://www.google.com/thispagedoesnotexist.htm

Examine HTTP status codes rather than page titles:

[Can Prototype or JQuery return an HTTP status code on an AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140456/can-prototype-or-jquery-return-an-http-status-code-on-an-ajax-request)