# http get request status

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, httpwebrequest, xmlhttprequest

I am using jQuery for sending HTTP request. Below is the code. I want to get the status code of HTTP request.

Does anyone know, how to get the status?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var url="http://www.google.com";
     $.get(url, function(data,status) {
        alert(status); 
       // This doesn't alert me status           
      // I want to alert request status code as "200" i.e. ok
            });
      // on Failure also need the status code of this request.
    });
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140456/can-prototype-or-jquery-return-an-http-status-code-on-an-ajax-request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

---

#### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/adoyaz)

---

```
$.get(url, function(data,status, xhr) {
    alert(xhr.status);
});
```

Comment: Sarfraz, I tried this, console.log(status) doesn't console the status. See my code.

Comment: Umesh, try passign the status argument into the function:
 $.get(url, function(data,status) { console.log(status);}

Comment: sorry, I did that also, but it didn't work. but, does it give on Fail status also ?

Comment: @Umesh: Answer is updated with working example, sorry I didn't put it up fine initially.

Comment: ok.Thanks Sarfraz. what if url is wrong.On Failure, I needed failed status code also. For example 1. url="asdasdg"

Comment: @Umesh: It will give you status code on legitimate urls and not dummy string.

Comment: yeah, Actually, the function will be called on Success only :) May be drawback of jQuery. Let's wait, if anyone can answer this to me.